# Order of points returned by detectCheckerboardPoints

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

The order of points returned by the CV-fcn detectCheckerboardPoints is defined in the documentation:
[image]

Numbers first increase along the short side of the checkerboard, then along the long side. But how exactly is the origin defined? It must be in the corner of the chessboard, which would leave 4 options. If we state, that there must be a black square to the outside of the origin we still have 2 options.

Now have a look at these two images taken of the same checkerboard with different cameras and the result of detectCheckerboardPoints plotted on them:
[image]

As we can see, the origin is in the left upper corner in the left image supporting the possibility of the outside black square (squares appear inverted in both images). We can also see that the numbering is pretty different for both images. If I wanted to calculate a stereo camera calibration or an image registration I would need corresponding point pairs. So I guess my question is twofold:

1. How exactly is the ordering of the image points returned by detectCheckerboardPoints defined? How many options are there?
2. How do I make sure that I get matching point pairs when running detectCheckerboardPoints for two images of the same checkerboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an asymmetric checkerboard where one side has the even number of squares and the other odd, then there is only one way to set the origin so that the square outside of it is black, the long side is the X-axis, the X-axis points to the right, and the Y-axis points down. This results in a right-handed coordinate system, with the Z-axis pointing into the board.

In the picture from the documentation, if you move the origin to the other black square, then either the short side has to become the X-axis, or the X-axis has to change direction.

In your particular case you have a problem, because the colors of the squares are reversed in the IR image. This will cause the order of the detected points to be different. If you want to calibrate these two cameras as a stereo pair, you have to either change the IR camera settings to reverse the image intensities, or do it yourself programmatically before you calibrate.

Comment: True, if we define the axes to be like you stated and a black square has to be outside of the origin, there is only one possibility - I checked the Mathworks code, they indeed make sure the outside square is black. As for the point matching: Either you have to make sure that your board is asymmetric and black squares appear black in both modalities (as you said) or you can write a method putting points in correct order by using the orientation of the determined x and y-axis to determine the appropriate origin.